# How to not re-initialize the pretrained loaded model in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have loaded a pretrained model (`Model 1`) using the following code:

```
def load_seq2seq_model(sess):


    with open(os.path.join(seq2seq_config_dir_path, 'config.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        saved_args = pickle.load(f)

    # Initialize the model with saved args
    model = Model1(saved_args)

    #Inititalize Tensorflow saver
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    # Checkpoint 
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(seq2seq_config_dir_path)
    print('Loading model: ', ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)

    # Restore the model at the checkpoint
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    return model
```

Now, I want to train another model (`Model 2`) from scratch which will take the output of the `Model 1`. But for that I need to define a session and load the pre-trained model and initialize the model `tf.initialize_all_variables()`. So, the pre-trained model will also get initialized.

Can anyone please tell me how to train the `Model 2` after getting the output from the pre-trained model `Model 1` properly?

What I am trying is given below -

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Initialize all the variables of the graph
    seq2seq_model = load_seq2seq_model(sess)
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    .... Rest of the training code goes here....
```

Comment: Have you tried initializing BEFORE importing Model 1?

Comment: I don't know the exact procedure. I tried that. That is working also. But if anyone could tell me the correct procedure I can be certain.

Answer (score 1):

All variables that are restored using a saver don't need to be initialized. Therefore, instead of using `tf.initialize_all_variables()` you can use `tf.variables_initializer(var_list)` to only initialize the weights of the second network.

To get a list of all the weights of the second network you can create the `Model 2` network in a variable scope:

```
with tf.variable_scope("model2"):
    model2 = Model2(...)
```

Then use

```
model_2_variables_list = tf.get_collection(
    tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, 
    scope="model2"
)
```

to get the variable list of the `Model 2` network. Finally you can create the initialisier for the second network:

```
init2 = tf.variables_initializer(model_2_variables_list)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Initialize all the variables of the graph
    seq2seq_model = load_seq2seq_model(sess)
    sess.run(init2)
    .... Rest of the training code goes here....
```

Comment: NotFoundError is coming up. Seems, It is trying to load the model2 also.

Comment: Changing the order of loading solved the problem I guess!

Comment: @AvijitDasgupta Does the NotFoundError appear when running `saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)`? If yes, make sure you initialize the saver (`saver = tf.train.Saver()`) *before* you initialize the 2nd network (so after `model = Model1(...)` but before  `model = Model2(...)`). Otherwise the saver will try to load both networks resulting in NotFoundError.